# litecoin constants and prefixes

Tags: litecoin, address-format, wallet-import-format

Is there any list of litecoin constants available?
Something like [Bitcoin list of address prefixes](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what I've gathered so far regarding the different version bytes for each type of Litecoin public address:

#### Mainnet:

- p2pkh L-address (`LM2WMpR1Rp6j3Sa59cMXMs1SPzj9eXpGc1`): `0x30`
- p2sh deprecated 3-address (`3MSvaVbVFFLML86rt5eqgA9SvW23upaXdY`): `0x05` (same as bitcoin's mainnet p2sh)
- p2sh new M-address (`MTf4tP1TCNBn8dNkyxeBVoPrFCcVzxJvvh`): `0x32`
- native segwit bech32 address (`ltc1q8c6fshw2dlwun7ekn9qwf37cu2rn755u9ym7p0`): prefix `ltc`, version `1`

#### Testnet:

- p2pkh m- or n-address (`mipcBbFg9gMiCh81Kj8tqqdgoZub1ZJRfn`): `0x6f` (same as bitcoin's testnet p2pkh)
- p2sh deprecated 2-address (`2N2PJEucf6QY2kNFuJ4chQEBoyZWszRQE16`): `0xc4`
- p2sh new Q-address (`QVk4MvUu7Wb7tZ1wvAeiUvdF7wxhvpyLLK`): `0x3a`
- native segwit bech32 address (`tltc1qyw3c0rvn6kk2c688y3dygvckn57525y8emy4p5`): prefix `tltc`, version `1`

This is the [Litecoin project's converter](https://litecoin-project.github.io/p2sh-convert/) between old and new p2sh address format.
And this is an [online base58check decoder](http://lenschulwitz.com/base58) to check the version byte.

Answer (score 4):

L - Legacy, Non-P2SH (Pay to script hash) address prefix

3 - P2SH prefix that's backwards compatible to the M prefix. When I say backwards compatible, I mean that there is a 3 address and an M address that point to the same address (Reference: https://blog.trezor.io/litecoins-new-p2sh-segwit-addresses-843633e3e707)

M - Current P2SH address prefix

Litecoin WIF Prefixes: 6 (0x36) and 7 (0x37)

Comment: do you also know the prefixes for WIF and the hex values?

Comment: Sure - I just added the WIF prefixes (including hex) to my above answer

Comment: As of Litecoin Core version v0.21.2rc6 bech32 WIFs (including hdseed) have prefix B0 (decimal 176)